# .htaccess redirect old url syntax to new Rewrite Rule syntax

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

**Hello**

I want avoid duplicate links with a redirect for All links not rewritten by .htaccess

**For example:**

.htaccess Rewrite Rule :

> RewriteRule ^watch-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?page=watch&id=$1 [NC,L]

**Redirect with variable, Something Like :**

```
index.php?page=watch&id=$var **redirect to** watch-$var.html
```

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?page=watch&id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /watch-%1.html? [L,R]
```

Comment: watch-5166.html?page=watch&id=5166

Comment: @AnassElFakir sorry, forgot a `?`

Answer (score 0):

**what about this Rules :**

```
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^query.html$ query.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search-([^/.-]+)\.html$ index.php?page=search&q=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search-([^/.-]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?page=search&q=$1&p=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^review-([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?page=review&id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^watch-([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?page=watch&id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^genre-([^/.-]+)\.html$ index.php?page=filter&genre=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^genre-([^/.-]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?page=filter&genre=$1&p=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Annee-([^/.-]+)\.html$ index.php?page=filter&Annee=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Annee-([^/.-]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?page=filter&Annee=$1&p=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Origine-([^/.-]+)\.html$ index.php?page=filter&Origine=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Origine-([^/.-]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?page=filter&Origine=$1&p=$2 [NC,L]
```